How can I deploy my Next.js 14 application on an IIS server?
error msg for config fileI have an IIS server currently hosting PHP applications located in C://inetpub/wwwroot/phpapp, and the server is pointing to a domain. I want to deploy my Next.js 14 application so that it is accessible at mydomain.com/mynextapp.
I have tried using iisnode and IIS Manager but have been unable to get it working. Additionally, my IP is configured to point to a domain. How can I configure IIS to serve my Next.js application under the specified path mydomain.com/mynextapp
my web.config

Steps are simple if you use HttpPlatformHandler https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-next-js-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

my apllication has both frontend and backend. and following this blog i encountered an error -- configuration file is not well-formed xml

What exactly is the error page? You have to edit the question to reveal that. Keep in mind the situation can be rather tricky, and a single change in error code can be caused by a completely different cause, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage

but have been unable to get it working, Is there any error message? And configuration file is not well-formed xml , the configuration of  config file may be in error. Please provide the code of Web.config.
